# How hide navigation bar always back from any view directly using NavigationView?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I am using xcode-14.2 & minimum target version 14. I have three views `ContentView`, `Welcome` & `FundTransfer. Here is my case.

1. ContentView - Load first view & navigationBarHidden is working. When `Welcome` page button click it goes to `Welcome` page
2. Welcome view - When `Fund Transfer` button is clicked, it goes to `FundTransfer` view
3. `FundTransfer` - when `Log out` button is clicked, it goes to `ContentView`

It goeslike: ContentView-> FundTransfer-> ContentView

Problem: When it goes from `FundTransfer` view to `ContentView` it shows navigationBar. That means when back from `FundTransfer` view to `ContentView` shows navigationBar which was hidden at the first.

How do I hide navigation bar always back from any view directly to `ContentView`?

Here is my code:
**ContentView:**

```
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State private var showWelcome = false
        @State var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool = true
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack(alignment: .customCenter,spacing: 0){
                            
                            VStack {
                                SubmitButton(action: {
                                    self.showWelcome = true
                                }) {
                                    Text("Welcome page")
                                }
                            }
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: Welcome(), isActive: $showWelcome) { EmptyView() }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                .navigationBarTitle("") //this must be empty
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

**Welcome View:**

```
    struct Welcome: View {
        @State private var showFundTransfer = false
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .customCenter,spacing: 0){
                        VStack {
                            SubmitButton(action: {
                                showFundTransfer = true
                            }) {
                                Text("Fund Transfer")
                            }
                        }
                        
                        NavigationLink(destination: FundTransfer(), isActive: $showFundTransfer) { EmptyView() }
                    }
                }
                
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            
        }
    }
```

**FundTransfer View:**

```
        struct FundTransfer: View {
        @State var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool = true
        @State private var logon = false
        var body: some View {
            
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(alignment: .customCenter,spacing: 0){
                        SubmitButton(action: {
                                self.logon = true
                           
                        }) {
                            Text("Log out")
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: ApplicationSwitcher(), isActive: $logon) { EmptyView() }.opacity(0)
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            
        }
    }
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Add .navigationBarHidden(true) in NavigationLink also for eg:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ApplicationSwitcher()
.navigationBarHidden(true), isActive: $logon) { EmptyView() }.opacity(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

In ContentView add "navigationBarHidden(true)" after the closure of NavigationView instead of VStack as mentioned below:

```
NavigationView {
...
}.navigationBarTitle("")
 .navigationBarHidden(true)
 .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

[image]